# Set different splash screen time on different application launch in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I want to show splash screen of different time on different launch. First time application launch i show splash screen till get all data from server , but i store this data in database . next time i get data from data base . this time i want to show splash screen only for 2 sec ..
Can you give me some suggestion

Thanks

Comment: What about a generic splash screen set in your config.xml, and then use an HTML-based splash screen?

Comment: Hi every thing is fine  in blackberry or in IOS. i am facing problem in android only.i used this code

Comment: public class PqrActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html",7000);
     //   super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
      //  super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // set scrollbar style
        
    }
}

Comment: <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />

Answer (score 0):

Cordova (PhoneGap) has a function `navigator.splashscreen.hide();` that you can call to explicitly hide the splash screen. This has been available on iOS since quite some time and is available on Android since v1.8.
You should be able to use that to hide the splashscreen once your data is loaded.

**EDIT**

[This blog](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html) shows how to show the splashscreen until the app is loaded.

Comment: is there any way in android to show splash until application load.?